# Editor for writing in tandem

Tags: eclipse, editor, webstorm, dreamweaver, adobe-brackets

I'm working with a couple of student interns, showing them proof-of-concepts. 
The amount of code we are writing is extremely small - snippets. I don't have to worry about version control or branches.

What I'm looking for is the simplest html editor for two people to be sharing a single document, not at the same time. In other words, it's ok if I totally overwrite his change if we are both making changes at the same time. In fact, that's preferred!

If we were on a local machine, I could use Notepad++. But since the code is on my VPS, then we are making changes in Dreamweaver and pushing changes up. That's too complicated because I make a change and he doesn't get the change unless he downloads it. We need to make the changes directly on the server with no intermediary steps. And when I make a change to his document, it reloads on his screen.

It needs to be as simple as two people using Notepad++ to change a file on a networked drive.
Remote Desktop only allows 1 person to remote in at a time.
Hmm... I wonder if that's really a restriction or if I could increase the number of concurrent users.

Hmm... I wonder if I could add my VPS drive as a networked drive? That would be slick...

Comment: Atom based: [Atom-pair](https://blog.pusher.com/atom-pair/), Firepad [1](https://atom.io/packages/firepad), [2](https://firepad.io/); [Etherpad](http://etherpad.org/) and more...

Comment: *"Remote Desktop only allows 1 person to remote in at a time"* That's for desktop OS. The server (2008+) allows at least 2 people (licensed for administrative tasks" though), otherwise proper Terminal Services (or whatever they called these days) licenses are required. Other than that: TeamViewer, VNC or even Skype/Chrome to share your dekstop with another person (user connects to you or other way around).